# Using xml structure as quartz.net job-data-map entry

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, quartz.net

I need to configure my Quartz.net job with xml configuration, so I have the following code in my quartz.xml config:

```
<job>
  <name>my_job</name>
  <group>job_group_2</group>
  <description>...</description>
  <job-type>Something.Somewhere.MyJob, Something.Somewhere</job-type>
  <job-data-map>
    <entry>
      <key>sources</key>
      <value>
        <sources>
          <source>
            <partnerId>1</partnerId>
            <ourPartnerId>2</ourPartnerId>
            <currency>971</currency>
            <path>test</path>
          </source>
        </sources>
      </value>
    </entry>
  </job-data-map>
</job>
```

In my code I want to get the xml structure under **sources** tag as string, like this

```
public class PayOnlineImportJob : IJob
{
    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var data = context.MergedJobDataMap;

        var sourcesXml = data.GetString("sources");

        // sourcesXml should be:

        // <sources>
        //  <source>
        //   <partnerId>1</partnerId>
        //   <ourPartnerId>2</ourPartnerId >
        //   <currency>971</currency>
        //   <path>test</path>
        //  </source>
        // </sources>
    }
}
```

When I run my service, the job is not getting fired. However if I replace everything inside **value** tag with simple **test**, it does work. Is there a way to put xml structure into **value** tag ?

Comment: Can you post what you want as output?  It is not clear from your description.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I've updated the question

Comment: See following codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32490/Custom-Configuration-Sections-for-Lazy-Coders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the JobDataMap is only storing a list of key value pairs.
So what you are trying todo is not possible.
You might rather store this structure in app.config,appSettings.config or web.config and read it from there instead.